# What is the difference between "unknown column" and "missing columns" error messages in ClickHouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Seems like "missing columns" happens when column doesn't physically exists. But what is the point of "unknown column" if CH actually knows about the column to say it's "unknown" and not "missing"?

Comment: Show us examples.

Comment: Look to stracktrace, Luke